# Acessar atributos private através de um loop em php

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma classe para minha interação com o banco de dados e preciso montar meus comandos DML com base numa instancia de classe passada.

```
    foreach($obj as $key => $value){
        //monta comando DML 
    }
```

Isso só funciona caso os atributos da classe forem public, no caso de private esse foreach não dá nenhum loop.
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso? Ou a única forma seria obrigar que o objeto passado possua um método que retorne seus próprios atributos?

Comment: Dá com reflexão, mas, sem colocar um exemplo não tem como opinar com certeza, e nem sempre é bom fazer isso...

Comment: "Ou a única forma seria obrigar que o objeto passado possua um método que retorne seus próprios atributos?"-- Sim, isto se chama encapsulamento. Normalmente usamos o nome do atributo prefixado por "get"